# D3: ordinal scale returning undefined in part of its range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an ordinal scale that is returning `undefined` over the second part of its domain.

```
// Return an array of all dates between date1 and date2 inclusive.
function days_in_range(date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2)
        return [];

    var date  = new Date(date1.getTime());
    var dates = [];
    while (date <= date2) {
        dates.push(new Date(date));
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
    }
    return dates;
}

min_date = new Date("2015-10-12");
max_date = new Date('2015-11-10');
the_dates = days_in_range(min_date, max_date);
xx_scale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(the_dates).rangeRoundBands([0, 790])

xx_scale(new Date('2015-10-12')); // Returns 4.
xx_scale(new Date('2015-10-24')); // Returns 328.
xx_scale(new Date('2015-10-25')); // Expect 355, but returns undefined.
```

From 2015-10-25 to end of range, I get undefined.  From beginning of domain until 2015-10-24, I get reasonable numbers.

The `days_in_range()` function does seem to be returning correctly.  I reproduce it here just to be complete.

Setting `max_date` to 2015-10-26 produces the same break (between 24 and 25).

Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Dates in an ordinal scale?  I'd read this [bit of documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_domain) (and the warning) carefully.  I'd suggest a nice [time scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold (three-fold if we count me being a dufus):

1. Domain values are strings, so I would have done well to convert back to year-month-day values after computing `the_days`.
2. The daylight savings time change happened between 2015-10-24 and 2015-10-25.  So the *Date* value changed from Date `2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z` to `Date 2015-10-25T01:00:00.000Z` as returned by `days_in_range()`, but `new Date('2015-10-25')` returns `Date 2015-10-25T00:00:00.000Z`.  Note the one hour shift.